# Regex for finding all numbers in a larger number

Tags: regex, expression

I am new to regular expressions. I am looking for a regular expression to find all numbers within a larger number.

For example, the number `12345`.

I would like the regex to find:
 `1,2,3,4,5,12,23,34,45,123,234,345,1234,2345,and 12345`.

I am using notepad++ right now to learn. I simply have the string 12345 and am using the "find" option. The idea being that I can insert a regular expression to find "1" then press "find next" and it will find "2" then "find next" and it will find "3" and so on all the way up to "`12345`". If it isn't possible for a regular expression to provide me this list, please let me know of a way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Is the input string going to always be all digits? Or is part of the task to extract numbers first?

Comment: Let's assume so. I'm not sure of the "task"...A list of the numbers would be cool but I'm not a developer and I don't know how to "extract" the list of numbers.

Comment: You should use the right tool for the right job. Regex isn't that tool. What kinds of programmatic solutions are you able to use?

Comment: I have access to a linux box. I guess a shell script or a perl script or something could be used, but I am inexperienced as far as scripting and any programming languages go. This small task was just a step for nudging myself to begin learning some things about regex and what it is capable of, along with any other knowledge that I can get out of it.

Answer (score 5):

From what i know you cannot do this. A regexp can match only one set of characters at a given position, so you cannot at different times with the same regexp match 1 and 12. This should be done using an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

From the patterns of numbers you have supplied. If I am not mistaken what you want a set of numbers that contains the same sets of digits from a supplied string of number.

ie. `1,2,3,4,5,12,23,34,45,123,234,345,1234,2345,and 12345` all contain the digits from the string `12345`.

This should be possible using a regex like `\b[12345]+\b` or if the total no. of digits has to be less than 5, it could be `\b[12345]{1,5}\b`. But if you are asking for a number numerically less than `12345` that will not be possible via. regex.